# React Memory Leaks Caused by Intersection Observer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools

**Background Info:** My React app was crashing on mobile. Chrome dev tools indicated garbage collection wasn't triggering. Looking into the heap the top constructors by retained size were all referencing intersection observor (used for infinite scrolling in many of my react components).

**Question**: How can I go about fixing the memory leaks caused by intersection observor? Is there a way to trigger garbage collection when the components unmount?

**Sample Component using Intersection Observor for Infinite Scroll:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { uuid, fabricateTimeStamp, getRandom } from '../containers/helperFunctions'
import { avatarQuery } from '../words'
import quote from 'inspirational-quotes'
import history from '../history'
import { thumbsUp, thumbsDown, arrowDrop } from './svgs'
import { 
  fetchAvatars as callAvatarsAPI, 
  fetchVideos as callVideosAPI } from '../containers/api'

const ActivityFeed = (props) => {
  const [firstRenderDone, setFirstRenderDone] = useState()
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const mobile = window.innerWidth <= 600
    if (mobile) fetchAvatars('woman', 3)
    if (!mobile) fetchAvatars('woman', 6)
    if (history.location.pathname.includes('/video/') || history.location.pathname.includes('/search/')) {
      document.querySelector('.activityFeedContainer').classList.toggle('hide')
    }
  }, [])

  // if user clicks nav button, remove all comments generated by infinite scroll
  useEffect(() => {
    setComments(prevState => (prevState.slice(0, 8)))
  }, [props.button])

  // INFINITE SCROLL
  // Callback is triggered when ref is set in mapCommentsToHTML
  const observer = useRef()
  const lastActivityPost = useCallback(lastPostNode => {
    observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      const lastPost = entries[0]
      if (lastPost.isIntersecting) fetchAvatars(getRandom(avatarQuery), 6)
    })
    if (lastPostNode) observer.current.observe(lastPostNode)
  })

  const fetchAvatars = async (query, amount) => {
    let response = await callAvatarsAPI(query, amount)
    response = response.data.hits
    mapCommentsToHTML(response)
  }

  const mapCommentsToHTML = (response) => {
    const picsMappedToHTML = response.map((pic, index) => {
      return ( 
        <div className="commentWrapper" key={uuid()} ref={response.length === index + 1 ? lastActivityPost : null}>
          <div className="avatarPlaceholder--comments">
          {props.page === 'channel' 
            ? <img 
                className="avatarPlaceholder--img" 
                src={
                  props.userAvatar.previewURL ? props.userAvatar.previewURL 
                  : props.userAvatar.userImageURL === "" ? 'https://i.imgur.com/ZwDgXSF.jpg' 
                  : props.userAvatar.userImageURL}
                alt="An Activity Feed User Avatar" />

            : <Link to={`/channel/${pic.id}`}> 
                <img 
                  className="avatarPlaceholder--img" 
                  src={pic.previewURL}
                  alt="An Activity Feed User Avatar" />
              </Link>
          }
          </div>
          <div className="commentContainer" >
            <Link to={`/channel/${pic.id}`}> 
              <h5 className="commentorName">{props.page === 'channel' ? props.userName : pic.user}</h5>
            </Link>
            <span className="dateOfComment">{fabricateTimeStamp(index)}</span> 
            <p className={`${props.page}-comment`}>{quote.getQuote().text}</p>
            <div className="thumbs">
              <span className="thumbsUpIcon">
                {thumbsUp(16)}
              </span>
              <span className="thumbsDownIcon">
                {thumbsDown(16)}
              </span>
            </div>
            <p className="replyText">REPLY</p>
            <div className="viewReplies">
              <span className="arrowDrop">
                {arrowDrop()}
              </span>
              View {Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 2} Replies
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    })
    setComments(prevState => ([...prevState, ...picsMappedToHTML]))
  }

  return (
    <aside className="activityFeedContainer">
      <h1 className={`${props.page}--activity-feed-title`}>Activity Feed</h1>
      <hr className="home--activityfeed-hr" />
      <div className="commentSection--activityfeed">
        {comments}
      </div>
    </aside>
  )
}
export default ActivityFeed
```

**Chrome Performance Timeline** (dip @ 27 secs is due to clicking an `<a>` tag which triggered page refresh)

[image: Memory Leak]

**Heap Snapshots:**

[image: Heap Snapshot]
[image: Heap Snapshot 2]
[image: Heap Snapshot 3]
[image: Heap Snapshot 4]

Comment: Ideally, I'd put that Intersection Observer thing inside useEffect hook, and when component is unmounted I'd just call observer.unobserve()

Comment: This was a bug in chrome and other browsers. Chrome bug ticket: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1220041

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to stop observing at some point , you might want to

call [disconnect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/disconnect) on your IntersectionObserver when you unmount